# Why static methods of Parent Class gets hidden in Child Class?

Tags: java, inheritance, static, polymorphism, method-hiding

This is psuedo-code

```
class A
{
  public static void m1()
  {
    System.out.println("Parent");
  }
}

class B extends A
{
  public static void m1()
  {
    System.out.println("Child");
  }
}
```

This code compiles successfully. Having an @Override annotation throws a compilation error. So please explain the concept about method hiding.
Does the Parent static method gets inherited in Child ?

Comment: Static methods belong to a class. They are inherited but cannot be overriden.

Comment: Please explain the concept

Comment: Read this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `static` method belongs to a `class` and not an instance of the `class`. For this reason, the call to a `static` method is always resolved using the reference type and not the instance type.

Runtime polymorphism only applies to instance methods. Therefore, both the following calls to `m1` in the example program will result in `m1` from `A` being called.

```
A aReferenece = new B(); 
A.m1();  
aReference.m1();
```

Since the instance type doesn't have any role to play in deciding which method gets called, being able to override a `static` method makes no sense since the method call is resolved at compile time itself.

That said, `static` methods can still be inherited and therefore be redefined/hidden by the subclass.